# onChange not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with a jquery dropdown menu. It is almost done, but for some reason I can't get the onChange working.

```
<select id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select" ONCHANGE="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" >
    <option value="-1" selected>Selecione uma categoria</option>
    <option value="1" class="icon-google-plus">Massa Muscular</option>
    <option value="2" class="icon-facebook">Resistência</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com" class="icon-twitter" >Vitaminas</option>
    <option value="4" class="icon-github">Emagrecimento</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What browser(and version) are you having the issues with?

Comment: You need to refer to `location` as either `document.location` or `location.href` in order to redirect the browser.

Comment: Okay, so where's jQuery in here?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I've re-added the jQuery tag since he mentions it in the question which means it's open to be used in the answer.  It will get more exposure with the relevant libraries tagged :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `location.href`:

```
<select id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select"
        ONCHANGE="location.href = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" >
------------------^
```

**Explanation**

The keyword `location` is the Object. The `href` property of the `location` object says the URL.

**Full Code:**

```
<select id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select" ONCHANGE="location.href = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" >
    <option value="-1" selected>Selecione uma categoria</option>
    <option value="1" class="icon-google-plus">Massa Muscular</option>
    <option value="2" class="icon-facebook">Resistência</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com" class="icon-twitter" >Vitaminas</option>
    <option value="4" class="icon-github">Emagrecimento</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is this different from browser to browser, because his code works fine for me in chrome, just using `location` (obviously, only option Vitaminas).

Comment: "window.location = 'http://www.example.com' is a synonym of window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com'." as quoted from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location

Comment: That's odd. I am using chrome as well, and I tested in Mozilla too. So far, without sucess.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<select id="cd-dropdown">
    <option disabled selected>Select</option>
    <option value="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
</select>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#cd-dropdown").on('change', function(){
    var url = $("option:selected", this).val();
    window.location = url;
});
```

[Whenever a new value is assigned to the location object, a document will be loaded using the URL as if window.location.assign() had been called with the modified URL.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location)

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer this simpler code:

```
onchange="location.href = this.value;"
```

Here ***this*** is the select object.

Your code here:

```
<select id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select" onchange="location.href = this.value;" >
    <option value="-1" selected>Selecione uma categoria</option>
    <option value="1" class="icon-google-plus">Massa Muscular</option>
    <option value="2" class="icon-facebook">Resistência</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com" class="icon-twitter" >Vitaminas</option>
    <option value="4" class="icon-github">Emagrecimento</option>
</select>
```